# MockMVC controller test NoSuchBeanDefinitionException on the Repository

Tags: spring, unit-testing

I am using Spring Boot and am trying to test my controller. I get a nasty NoSuchBeanDefinitionException no qualifying bean MyRespository class. The repository is autowired in the service class.  Does anyone know how I can fix this problem? Thanks.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(UserVehicleController.class)
public class UserVehicleControllerTests {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @MockBean
    private UserVehicleService userVehicleService;

    @Test
    public void testExample() throws Exception {
        given(this.userVehicleService.getVehicleDetails("sboot"))
            .willReturn(new VehicleDetails("Honda", "Civic"));

        this.mvc.perform(get("/sboot/vehicle").accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN))
            .andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(content().string("Honda Civic"));
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added @AutoConfigureMockMvc and @MockBean for the class where the repository was @Autowired and the tests worked.